# plink.exe : Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, putty, plink

We are developing a winforms client with C#, for sending SSH commands using plink.exe. We have got the following method. But we execute it, standard error gives "FATAL ERROR : Server unexpectedly closed network connection".

The same command (plink.exe + arguments) is executed successfully in the command line.

Any idea?

Thanks.

```
    public string SendSSHCommand(string host, string userName, string password, string commandFile, string logPath, int maxRetryCount)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        string commandText = "plink.exe";

        Process sshProcess = new Process();
        sshProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(commandText);
        sshProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} -P 22 -ssh -l {1} -pw {2} <\"{3}\"> \"{4}\"", host, userName, password, commandFile, logPath);

        sshProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Parameters.RootDirectory;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        sshProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //sshProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        _logger.Log("SSH Command : " + commandText + " " + sshProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);

        int iteration = 0;

        while (iteration <= maxRetryCount)
        {
            iteration++;
            sshProcess.Start();

            //Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait for two seconds.

            sshProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("y");
            sshProcess.WaitForExit();

            string output = sshProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = sshProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            _logger.Log("STANDARD OUTPUT : " + output);
            _logger.Log("STANDARD ERROR : " + error);

            if (File.Exists(logPath))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(logPath))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                File.Delete(logPath);
            }
            else
            {
                result = "NO RESULT FILE";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) // retry needed.
            {
                _logger.Log("SSH command failed. Retrying after 5 seconds...");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            else
            {
                break;  // command executed. no retry needed.
            }
        }

        if (iteration >= maxRetryCount)
        {
            _logger.Log("Max retry count is reached.");
            throw new Exception("SSH command failed after " + maxRetryCount.ToString() + " attempts.\nFailed command :\n" + commandText + " " + sshProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Tried UseShellExecute = true?

Comment: If I set it true, I cannot redirect standard input, output and error.

Comment: Not sure how plink works, but can it somehow be incompatible for redirecting output? Can you "proxy" it through a "cmd /k plink.exe ..."?

Comment: I created a "quiet.exe" app that launches any console app without showing any window. ShellExecute = false. And I am running this shortcut with no errors. Quiet.exe plink.exe -v -X -l username -pw mypwd servername "/usr/bin/xterm" -ls. Have you tried a different version of plist? (Plink version 0.63.0.0)

Comment: This works for me: SendSSHCommand("server", "user", "pwd", "/usr/bin/xterm", @"/tmp", 1); when sshProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} -ssh -X -l {1} -pw {2} \"{3}\" \"{4}\"", host, userName, password, commandFile, logPath); xterm popping up. Not sure if that will help you in any way. Notice the removal of "-P 22" and added "-X" (for display using xming)